# Where is the <kbd> tag in the guidelines

Tags: support

In the guidelines I cannot find the tag < kbd>

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

I've tried the same search 3 times, is it possible that it is missing?

I looked on that link first by reading it, that by looking for key, keybd, tag, button..

Comment: It's under the Inline HTML section in your link?

Comment: Question modified, can you please remove the downvote, and answer so that I can accept?

Comment: How/where are you searching?

Comment: I looked on that link first by reading it, that by looking for key, keybd, tag, button...

Comment: @Bart: no.. It seems funny but I didn't tried. The reason is really simple. Some tags are written with [ and some others with <. I had scrolled the guideline pages 3 times, I made some searches and I tried to use the [kbd] tag without success. As you well know the human brain is not like a computer. It works for associations and I associated the idea that I had already searched for that key. Do you want some evidence? I will provide (so you can understand how hurried can be your judgement). Give me just a second to find it. But strongly think that the presumption to be "better" is not nice.

Comment: @Bart: ok.. you are right.. I take stuff too much seriously, sorry

Comment: @Bart: ah, but look also to this stuff. This very downvoted question lead to a very interesting answer (read the last part of it). In case like this I would discourage the wrong voters. You think: "is this guy stupid or crazy?" - if the effort which we would like to give to SE is to classify "good" question for training a neural network for recognizing "nice" questions than the downvotes are nice. But if we instead want to spread knowledge the downvotes here completely went in the opposite directon lead by stupid human emotions. Think a bit of this crazy iphotesi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keyboard tag is in the [Inline HTML](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#html) section in editing help.

It is important to remember that Stack Overflow does not support some form of custom "keyboard markup" syntax.

Stack Overflow, as the editing help suggests, supports a strict subset of HTML. The `<kbd>` element is [standard HTML markup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/kbd).

The reason, I would imagine, it's not detailed as "Using keyboard markup" in the help docs is the same reason it doesn't explain what `<blockquote>`, `<hr>` and `<code>` are - they can't document HTML.